# how to combine dataframe return from function with multiprocessing module

Tags: python, dataframe, multiprocessing

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time



sql_server = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=vm-dwh02-stg;DATABASE=DWStaging;Trusted_Connection=yes;'

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": sql_server})
sqlengine = create_engine(connection_url)
sqlengine  = sqlengine.execution_options(autocommit=False)



def table_load(table_name,target_table,companycode):  
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=Fis',fast_executemany=True)
    query1 = 'Select * from ' + table_name
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query1,cnxn)
    df['COMPANYCODE']=companycode
    print('Table Loaded ......'+table_name)
###    df.to_sql(target_table, sqlengine, schema = 'dbo', if_exists='append',index=False,chunksize=5000)




table_name = []
    

table_name.append(('GLMH01','test_table',1))
table_name.append(('GLMH02','test_table',2))
table_name.append(('GLMH05','test_table',5))
table_name.append(('GLMH09','test_table',9))
table_name.append(('GLMH0A','test_table',10))
table_name.append(('GLMH0B','test_table',11))
table_name.append(('GLMH0C','test_table',12))




if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as p:
      p.starmap(table_load,table_name)
```

I am using above code to load data into table from multiple source table. But the process of loading data to sql server adds around 12 minutes..If i just create dataframe it take 5 minutes.

I tried using different paramters like chunksize and multi for df.to_sql but there is not improvement.

Is there any way I can combine all dataframe before loading ..rather than loading each one individually using the above code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'combine all dataframe before loading' ? You will need to combine once the data is loaded in dataframes, what's the point of combining them before loading ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem. Maybe because word `loading` usually is used as `loading from file` but you means `inserting to database`. Maybe you need to use `return df` in `table_load()` and then you could do `all_df = p.starmap(...)` and you would have all `dataframes` as list (in main process) and you could combine then into one `dataframe`. But `multiprocessing` has to send data using file/pickle and it may take some time.